# CURL & Wget returning response, Browser is timing out

Tags: linux

I am sending requests to a specific server on a cloud:

```
wget --header="Host: example.com" http://x.x.x.x:80/
curl -i -H"Host: example.com" http://x.x.x.x:80/
```

And it returns exactly as expected (a simple static file).  However, when I try and access it in a browser, the request times out.  I can't imagine it would be a user agent header issue, but then again, I don't really know what else it would be.

It isn't going to a load balancer or anything, should be going directly to the site.  Any ideas on why this might be happening?  I have my hosts file set to go to that specific IP address.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, the browser is ignoring the hosts file and is not connecting to the IP address you are expecting it to.

Comment: what does `curl -i example.com` return?

Comment: Is the browser configured to use a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. It turns out there was an setting overriding the request, sending it to a new port that wasn't opened by the firewall...

Comment: What setting, and where? This could help someone

Comment: Thanks, had a similar issue where curl worked from server, but I couldn't visit the site via browser. Turned out curl also didn't work if accessed from another server. had to enable firewall via `ufw allow`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the server to find out.

Can you see a request coming in to the webserver? (is there a tcp socket opened?)

What does the web server software log about the connection? Can you make it more verbose if it's not saying enough.

Failing that, tell us more about your webserver and its config.